# "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user" in R

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-oauth

This question has been asked many times for php, C# and some other programming languages. I don't find any information for R though and I can't derive a solution from the other topics.

I try to do facebook data mining in R with the package [Rfacebook](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rfacebook/Rfacebook.pdf):

```
library(devtools)
install_github("pablobarbera/Rfacebook/Rfacebook")
require("Rfacebook")
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="ID", app_secret="SECRET",extended_permissions = TRUE)
```

After authenticating, facebook already gives me an error (though I'm not sure, if it has anything to do with the problem):

[image]

For starters, I'd like to access my own profile now:

```
myProfile <- getUsers("me",token=fb_oauth)
```

and that's when the console display the following error:

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to make the user login to your app first, before you can get any information about them. And `read_stream` permission was removed with API v2.4 (and will be removed for all apps, no matter what API version they are using, on Oct. 6, 2105.)

Comment: I don't understand - isn't the login created when executing fbOAuth? If not,  could you please specify?

Comment: What @CBroe is saying is that more than likely the app ID you are using is on v2.4 which means that you cannot use the permission `read_stream`. More than likely what is happening with Rfacebook is that the `extended_permissions` in Rfacebook is out of date.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I am having the same issue. I don't think it's related to the out-of-date Rfacebook package and the Facebook API should automatically ignore this permission (as it says in the error).

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution back then.

Comment: even i m stuck on this now @doctaj